# Selective display of divs via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, hide, show

So I have a little hobbyist-level background in Javascript, CSS, HTML, MySQL and PHP. I'm currently working on a website which features a list of business locations.

I've set it up so that each location is listed on a page with it's own 'Contacts' link. The contact link activates JS which modifies the visible list of locations, making way for a list of locations-specific contacts at that organisation, off to one side.

These contact lists all sit on display: none, in the background, and are selectively set to display: block, depending on the id of the calling link.

Each contact list should also have an exit button, of sorts, to close the contact list for that location AND clicking on the Contacts link for any other location should update (replace) the displayed list of contacts appropriately.

I think what I have should work, but I seem to be missing something. The problem is that the contacts will only display for the first location: Somerset.

I would greatly appreciate any help in solving this issue :)

Essential code:

```js
function hideAll() {
  var i, curr, ar = ["people_Somerset", "people_Latrobe", "people_Hobart", "people_Smithton", "people_Launceston"];

  for (i = 0; i <= 4; i += 1) {
    curr = document.getElementById(ar[i]);
    if (curr.style.display === "block") {
      curr.style.display = "none";
    }

  }
}

function hideTitle() {
  document.getElementById("staff_h3").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function showTitle() {
  document.getElementById("staff_h3").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function makeWay() {
  //Modify CSS to make room for selected contact list

  var selection, i, j;

  // Narrow location list to 50%

  selection = document.getElementsByClassName("left_column");
  j = selection.length;

  for (i = 0; i < j; i += 1) {
    selection[i].style.width = "50%";
  }

  //Modify div.location
  selection = document.querySelectorAll("div.location");
  j = selection.length;

  for (i = 0; i < j; i += 1) {
    selection[i].style.float = "none";
    selection[i].style.width = "100%";
  }

  //Change title width

  selection = document.querySelectorAll("h2.lefttitle");
  j = selection.length;

  for (i = 0; i < j; i += 1) {
    selection[i].style.width = "40%";
  }
}

function resetCSS() {

  var selection, j, i;

  // Reset location list to 100%
  selection = document.getElementsByClassName("left_column");
  j = selection.length;

  for (i = 0; i < j; i += 1) {
    selection[i].style.float = "left";
    selection[i].style.width = "100%";
  }

  // div.location narrows and floats to the left
  selection = document.querySelectorAll("div.location");
  j = selection.length;

  for (i = 0; i < j; i += 1) {
    selection[i].style.float = "left";
    selection[i].style.width = "50%";
  }

  //Change title width
  selection = document.querySelectorAll("h2.lefttitle");
  j = selection.length;

  for (i = 0; i < j; i += 1) {
    selection[i].style.width = "auto";
  }
}

function rolo(object) {

  var staff = document.getElementById("staff_h3"),
    currentElement = document.getElementById("people_" + object.id.substr(5, 12)),
    i, j;

  //If closing a staff list, hide it and reset CSS
  if (object.id === "close_rolo" || currentElement.style.display === "block") {
    hideAll();
    hideTitle();
    resetCSS();
  } else {
    // Change staff section title
    staff.innerHTML = "Our People: " + object.id.substr(5, 12);

    // Change CSS
    makeWay();

    // Set people section title to visible

    showTitle();

    // Depending on Contacts link, display the appropriate block of people
    hideAll();
    currentElement.style.display = "block";
  }

}
```

```css
#locations {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
h2.lefttitle {
  padding-bottom: 0em;
  margin: 0;
}
#staff_h3 {
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
}
h2.righttitle {
  text-align: right;
}
#exit {
  float: right;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  margin-top: -3em;
  margin-left: 3em;
}
.display_none {
  display: none;
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
p.quote {
  margin-bottom: 0em;
}
h3.location {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
div.location ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 0em;
  padding-top: 0em;
}
div.location {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 19em;
}
div.column {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.left_column {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.right_column {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
img.location {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
div.staff_container {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}
div.stafflist {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
div.person {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  height: 6em;
}
h4.person {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
}
div.subtitle {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/showdiv.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/locations.css" type="text/css" />

<div id='locations'>
  <div class='left_column'>
    <h2 class='lefttitle'>Our Locations</h2>

    <div class='location'>
      <img class='location' src='img/locations/somerset.jpg' title='Somerset' />

      <ul>
        <li>
          <h3 class='location'>Somerset</h3>
        </li>
        <li>5 Reece Court
          <br/>Somerset</li>
        <br/>
        <li><a id="rolo_Somerset" onclick='rolo(this);return false;'>Contacts</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class='location'>
      <img class='location' src='img/locations/latrobe.png' title='Latrobe' />

      <ul>
        <li>
          <h3 class='location'>Latrobe</h3>
        </li>
        <li>3 Speedway Drive
          <br/>Latrobe</li>
        <br/>
        <li><a id="rolo_Latrobe" onclick='rolo(this);return false;'>Contacts</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class='location'>
      <img class='location' src='img/locations/launnie.png' title='Launceston' />

      <ul>
        <li>
          <h3 class='location'>Launceston</h3>
        </li>
        <li>379 Westbury Road
          <br/>Prospect</li>
        <br/>
        <li><a id="rolo_Launceston" onclick='rolo(this);return false;'>Contacts</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class='location'>
      <img class='location' src='img/locations/smithton.png' title='Smithton' />

      <ul>
        <li>
          <h3 class='location'>Smithton</h3>
        </li>
        <li>116 Nelson Street
          <br/>Smithton</li>
        <br/>
        <li><a id="rolo_Smithton" onclick='rolo(this);return false;'>Contacts</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class='location'>
      <img class='location' src='img/locations/hobart.jpg' title='Hobart' />

      <ul>
        <li>
          <h3 class='location'>Hobart</h3>
        </li>
        <li>43 Derwent Park Road
          <br/>Derwent Park</li>
        <br/>
        <li><a id="rolo_Hobart" onclick='rolo(this);return false;'>Contacts</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='right_column staff_container'>
    <h3 id='staff_h3' class='hidden lefttitle'>Our People</h3>
    <div id='people_Somerset' class='display_none location stafflist'>
      <a id='close_rolo' onclick='rolo(this);return false;'>
        <img id='exit' src='img/icons/exit.gif' title='Close Rolodex' />
      </a>
      <div class='left_column'>
        <!--First result-->

        <div class='person'>
          Somerset person one
        </div>
        <!-- Close person -->
      </div>
      <!-- Close column -->
      <div class='right_column'>
        <div class='person'>
          Somerset person two
        </div>
        <!-- Close person -->
      </div>
      <!-- Close column -->

      <div id='people_Latrobe' class='display_none location stafflist'>
        <a id='close_rolo' onclick='rolo(this);return false;'>
          <img id='exit' src='img/icons/exit.gif' title='Close Rolodex' />
        </a>
        <div class='left_column'>
          <!--First result-->

          <div class='person'>
            Latrobe person one
          </div>
          <!-- Close person -->
        </div>
        <!-- Close column -->
        <div class='right_column'>
          <div class='person'>
            Latrobe person two
          </div>
          <!-- Close person -->
        </div>
        <!-- Close column -->


        <div id='people_Launceston' class='display_none location stafflist'>
          <a id='close_rolo' onclick='rolo(this);return false;'>
            <img id='exit' src='img/icons/exit.gif' title='Close Rolodex' />
          </a>
          <div class='left_column'>
            <!--First result-->

            <div class='person'>
              Launceston person one
            </div>
            <!-- Close person -->
          </div>
          <!-- Close column -->
          <div class='right_column'>
            <div class='person'>
              Launceston person two
            </div>
            <!-- Close person -->
          </div>
          <!-- Close column -->

          <div id='people_Smithton' class='display_none location stafflist'>
            <a id='close_rolo' onclick='rolo(this);return false;'>
              <img id='exit' src='img/icons/exit.gif' title='Close Rolodex' />
            </a>
            <div class='person'>
              Smithton person one
            </div>
            <!-- Close person -->
          </div>
          <!-- Close column -->
          <div class='right_column'>
            <div class='person'>
              Smithton person two
            </div>
            <!-- Close person -->
          </div>
          <!-- Close column -->


          <div id='people_Hobart' class='display_none location stafflist'>
            <a id='close_rolo' onclick='rolo(this);return false;'>
              <img id='exit' src='img/icons/exit.gif' title='Close Rolodex' />
            </a>
            <div class='left_column'>
              <!--First result-->

              <div class='person'>
                Hobart person one
              </div>
              <!-- Close person -->
            </div>
            <!-- Close column -->
            <div class='right_column'>
              <div class='person'>
                Hobart person two
              </div>
              <!-- Close person -->
            </div>
            <!-- Close column -->


          </div>
          <!-- Close people_whatever -->
        </div>
        <!-- close outer right column -->
      </div>
      <!-- close locations -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: the following code snippets have not been tested in browser. I use my memory of how I've done similar UIs earlier.

I would suggest tying the contacts for each location together in HTML. Then use a simple `active` class or similar for the containing location and the following rule would show the corresponding contacts:

```
.location {
    /* positioning and such for non-selected locations */
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.location > .contacts {
    display: none;
}

.location.active {
    /* positioning and such for an active (selected) locations */
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}

.location.active > .contacts {
    display: block;
}
```

In JavaScript you could toggle the selected location using

```
var contact_display_buttons = document.querySelectorAll( '.contact-button' );

// You can extract this inline anonymous function in case you need to use it elsewhere.
contact_display_buttons.addEventListener( 'click', function( evt ) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var clicked_btn = evt.target;

    // If you need to close all contact lists before showing another, uncomment:
    /*
    var all_locations = document.querySelectorAll( '#locations .location' );
    all_locations.classList.remove( 'active' );
    */

    var parent = clicked_btn.parentElement;

    // Get the containing location element.
    while ( ! parent.classList.contains( 'location' ) && parent !== undefined ) {
        parent = parent.parentElement;
    }

    if ( parent !== undefined ) {
        parent.classList.toggle( 'active' );
    }
}, false );
```

`classList` might not be properly implemented in all browsers, but there are polyfills available. `addEventListener` may need an alternative for older IEs and such.

The underlying HTML structure could be the following:

```
<div id="locations">
    <div class="location">
        <div class="location-info">
            ...
            <button class="contact-button">Show contacts</button>
        </div>
        <div class="contacts">
            <ul>
                ...
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="location">
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Now if someone clicks the `.contact-button` element inside a `.location` element, the `.location`'s direct child `.contacts` will be shown and hidden in a toggle fashion.

Add some CSS animations to the mix if you want. JS animations will need some work in the `click` handler inside the above JS snippet.